# How to remove old schlage lock system

Tags: lock

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

There is no exposed screw, there is only a tiny hole in the handle.
Can't figure out how to open it.

Comment: If it's anything like the one I used to have, you have to use a straightened out paperclip (or some other hard wire) to poke inside that little hole to push in a small metal tab that holds the doorknob. Once you push it in the knob can be pulled off.